# Determine the DRAM size on a Cisco ASR1006

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, memory

We recently bought an ASR1006, and we have been told it has `16GB` DRAM memory, but I am little confused by the `show version` output, e.g. `processor with 9964723K/6147K bytes of memory`, which is showing `9G` memory.

What is `16777216K bytes of physical memory.` in the following output then?

```
cisco ASR1006 (RP2) processor with 9964723K/6147K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FXS1846Q06D
4 Ten Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
32768K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.
16777216K bytes of physical memory.
1933311K bytes of eUSB flash at bootflash:.
78085207K bytes of SATA hard disk at harddisk:.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`16777216K` is 16 GB of DRAM. Your ASR1006 has 16 GB of DRAM installed.

For the `processor with 9964723K/6147K bytes of memory`, the first number is the amount of memory available to software processes, or process memory. The second number is the amount which has been allocated for I/O memory (interface buffers). On the ASR1000 series, the two numbers don't add up to the total DRAM, as they do on many of the routers, because the IOS is running as a process under a Linux kernel.